# How do I see which columns throughout my database reference one particular column as a foreign key? Like a "reverse" foreign key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I've got a pretty big relational database and am working on the admin backend. I want to know which tables reference a column in one particular table.

For example: let's say I've got a table `products` with `id` as the primary index. I can have a lot of tables that reference this index, such as an `orders` table, a `user_bookmarks` table, and a `product_reviews` table. If I want to delete a particular product, I first need to do some work with the other tables--a simple "cascade" or "delete" directive wouldn't be enough. How do I get MySQL to tell me exactly which columns in which tables are referencing the `products.id` index?

Bonus question: is there a built-in way to get this info using phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE (REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME) = ('mydatabase', 'products')
```

---

Re your comment:

MySQL doesn't support recursive queries, so unfortunately there's no way to find the complete graph of foreign keys in a single query.  The best you could do is for each of the results of the above query, run the query again, substituting the TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME as the string constants in the WHERE clause (be careful not to enter into infinite loops if you have circular foreign keys).

Comment: Actually, is it possible to take this one step further and create a "tree" that would show the foreign key contraints of the results? Continuing from my example, if `product_reviews` referenced `products.id`, it would also show which tables reference `product_reviews`? Sorry if that's asking a bit too much =P

Answer (score 1):

Could you not read the Schema from the database into MySQL Workbench, and then use the tool to plot out the relationships between the tables?  I have not tried this myself, as I do the design in MySQL Workbench and then the mappings, etc... and then export to MySQL to create the database.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't thought of that. Good answer, too. Once the database is deployed, do you still use Workbench? How do you make changes to the DB?

Comment: I still use Workbench for all the schema edits and documentation.  However, the deploy changes since I am not creating a new database each time.  I have used other scripts to deploy, which usually compares the two tables (existing to new definition) and updates the existing table with the new definition as simple ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: In reading up on the MySQL Workbench page, it does seem to have a synchronize function now, but I have not used it.  I cannot comment on its effectiveness, but I have used the one with Microsoft SQL Server, and its scripting tool will show you how to change the table via SQL statements, which you can then submit to the server (SQL Server of course). Therefore, I am assuming that the MySQL Workbench will likely do this quite well also.